# Conditional for Intent ACTION on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, action

I want to open a link in a webview and when I click on a link, I want to open specific applications.
Example: When you click on a url with "google.com/maps", open the Google Maps application, when you click on a url containing "youtube.com", open the Youtube application, and when you click on a url containing "tel: , open the dialer. And if it's a regular url, browse normal in the webview.

It's possible?

Comment: Hey there & welcome to StackOverflow Andrelino! Your question is incomplete and has little chances to get answered as is. Please read the **[How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article & edit your question adding more information. Let's start with some snippets that you've worked on regarding the matter!

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for can be found in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/)